# FusedLocationProviderClient not giving correct Location

Tags: android, kotlin, google-maps

I am using `FusedLocationProviderClient` to get the location but it not giving correct Location (i.e. precise). The location it provides is 20 blocks away atleast which is not really a good solution for me.

LatLng i Need : `28.602205, 77.380126`

LatLng i receive: `28.600504,77.382864`

Here is code for the same

```js
val client = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)
var locationRequest = LocationRequest.create().apply {
  interval = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(20)
}
client.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, object: LocationCallback() {
  override fun onLocationAvailability(p0: LocationAvailability) {
    super.onLocationAvailability(p0)
  }

  override fun onLocationResult(p0: LocationResult) {
    super.onLocationResult(p0)
    var latLong = p0.lastLocation
    marker.position = LatLng(latLong!!.latitude, latLong.longitude)
    Log.d("sagar", "Location result: $p0")
  }
}, Looper.getMainLooper())
```

Comment: What's the Android target version? What's the permission level (approximate, precise, COARSE, FINE)? Are the results the the same when you have the strong internet connection and weak?

Comment: I have given the COARSE and FINE permissions both, and yes the results are same using good internet connection as well as poor.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Have you tried to put PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY in your LocationRequest? Just for testing purposes of your GPS signal bc it consumes too much battery. If it's still the same remote location, it's pretty curious - this priority combined with FINE always gives like the best results.